readlink(2) result is inconsistent with nested mount namespaces
When two nested mount namespaces are created using unshare(2) in a newly forked process; calling readlink(2) from the last namespace using an FD opened in the previous namespace returns a path that's missing it's mount point component.
I.e. /dev/zero becomes /zero and /mnt/disk/file becomes /file.
However, this does not seem to happen if there is a fork in between the two unshare calls. What does fork do that changes this behavior?
The C++ code below can demonstrate the problem. I've also attached it's output when ran on Linux 6.1.23.
It can optionally be provided a single argument "fork", which makes a fork right after the first namespace is created so that the second namespace is created in a different process that inherits the first namespace from the parent process.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string readlink_path(const std::string &path) {
    std::vector<char> buf(4096);
    ssize_t size = readlink(path.c_str(), buf.data(), buf.size());
    return size == -1 ? "" : std::string(buf.data(), static_cast<size_t>(size));
}
std::string readlink_fd(int fd) { return readlink_path("/proc/self/fd/" + std::to_string(fd)); }

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int fdFromFirstNS = -1, fdFromInitialNS = -1;
    /* Initial namespace */
    std::cout << readlink_path("/proc/self/ns/mnt") << '\n';
    fdFromInitialNS = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
    std::cout << "open() = " << fdFromInitialNS << '\n';
    std::cout << "readlink(" << fdFromInitialNS << ") = " << readlink_fd(fdFromInitialNS) << "\n\n";
    
    /* First namespace */
    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) != 0) goto END;
    std::cout << readlink_path("/proc/self/ns/mnt") << '\n';
    fdFromFirstNS = open("/dev/zero", O_RDONLY);
    std::cout << "open() = " << fdFromFirstNS << '\n';
    std::cout << "readlink(" << fdFromInitialNS << ") = " << readlink_fd(fdFromInitialNS) << '\n';
    std::cout << "readlink(" << fdFromFirstNS << ") = " << readlink_fd(fdFromFirstNS) << '\n' << std::endl;
    
    /* Fork if the first argument is "fork" */
    if (argc == 2 && std::string("fork") == argv[1]) {
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid)
        {
            waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
            goto END;
        }
        std::cout << "Forked. " << readlink_path("/proc/self/ns/mnt") << "\n\n";
    }
    
    /* Second namespace */
    if (unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) != 0) goto END;
    std::cout << readlink_path("/proc/self/ns/mnt") << '\n';
    std::cout << "readlink(" << fdFromInitialNS << ") = " << readlink_fd(fdFromInitialNS) << '\n';
    std::cout << "readlink(" << fdFromFirstNS << ") = " << readlink_fd(fdFromFirstNS) << '\n';
END:
    close(fdFromInitialNS);
    close(fdFromFirstNS);
}

g++ test.cpp && sudo ./a.out:
mnt:[4026532253]
open() = 3
readlink(3) = /dev/zero

mnt:[4026532259]
open() = 4
readlink(3) = /dev/zero
readlink(4) = /dev/zero

mnt:[4026532260]
readlink(3) = /dev/zero
readlink(4) = /zero

g++ test.cpp && sudo ./a.out fork:
mnt:[4026532253]
open() = 3
readlink(3) = /dev/zero

mnt:[4026532259]
open() = 4
readlink(3) = /dev/zero
readlink(4) = /dev/zero

Forked. mnt:[4026532259]

mnt:[4026532260]
readlink(3) = /dev/zero
readlink(4) = /dev/zero


fork creates a new parent process.
Given that unshare duplicates the parent process namespace on creating a new namespace, that has its importance:

no fork: fd=4 is created while namespace 4026532259 is active, but latter call to unshare copies from 4026532253 (the parent process namespace)

fork: fd=4 is created in namespace 4026532259, latter call to unshare copies from that namespace, since it's now the parent process' namespace.



Thank you for the answer but reading the kernel code, it looks like it just copies namespaces of the current process, without any references to the parent?

fork.c ksys_unshare
nsproxy.c unshare_nsproxy_namespaces
nsproxy.c create_new_namespaces
namespace.c copy_mnt_ns


Adding to my comment above, MS_PRIVATE mounts from the first NS do copy over to the second NS without the fork. That and the code I've linked leads me to believe that unshare is duplicating the NS of the current process and not the parent's NS.

I went entirely from the doc, which states: This flag has the same effect as the clone(2) CLONE_NEWNS flag. clone's doc says this: initialized with a copy of the namespace of the parent. Now, it's possible that "same effect" doesn't actually refer to the parenting relationship...
